# Pass sub-array in C to 1D array function

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, pass-by-reference

I have a function

```
void diff(double X[], double X_diff[], double length_X);
```

which takes an 1D array of doubles (X), performs the numerical derivative, and gives back the result (in X_diff). To this function I want to pass a sub-array ("vector") of a 2D array without modifying the function, but I don't know how to call it. I suspect it might be done with double pointers, but I have never used them before.

If I had to do it in MATLAB, and M was a 2D matrix, I would do something like

```
X_diff = diff(M(1,:));
```

How could I do this in C?

Comment: In C you can try to pass `&(M[i])` where i is the row you need. If it's a column, then is might be more complex.

Comment: @SibusisoMabuza - The above MATLAB syntax is for a row, so `&(M[i])` should be sufficient for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a array like

```
p[10][20];
q[10][20];
```

Now you can pass the address of the row for your API like

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
diff(p[i],q[i],length);
```